# Angular 2 : form, when book option, start and end date are not needed

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML:

```
<md-select placeholder="Type" required [(ngModel)]="request.type" (ngModelChange)="valueDateNeeded()">
<md-option *ngFor="let type of requestTypes" [value]="type.value">
 {{type.name}}
 </md-option>
 </md-select>
```

I want to get the value of the option that is chosen. To then link it to valueDateNeeded() so that i can set true or false depending on the value and then i can show or not show another div.

Comment: `[ngModel]="request.type" (ngModelChange)="valueDateNeeded($event)"` and `$event` holds your chosen value.

Comment: also, since you have your ngModel, if you use two-way binding, the value will be in `request.type`

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use `[(ngModel)]`

example

component.ts

```
public variableStore: any;
```

component.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="variableStore">
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select
```

The value will be inside `variableStore`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:- 
**component.html:-**

```
<md-select placeholder="Type" required [(ngModel)]="date" (ngModelChange)="valueDateNeeded($event)">
<md-option *ngFor="let type of requestTypes" [ngValue]="type.value">
 {{type.name}}
 </md-option>
 </md-select>
```

**component.ts**

```
date:any;
```

Change your [(ngModel)] name and declare this name in ts file as a variable.